# what is extended measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

in Kolmogorov's book he introduces the topic about extended measure.i don't really understand what it is about and why do we need it.please can you give me some information about it?it was really abstract for me.he introduced Jordan extended measure and Lebesgue extended measure, on semi-rings and rings.my question is: why do we need them and what are they?